# Spring Boot one to many unidirectional

Tags: spring, jpa

I have the entity Project and entity Cluster.
A Project can have multiple Clusters.
I don't want a third table to save this relationship. Just the Project ID saved to the Cluster.

This is my project Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String projectName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "cluster")
    private Set<Cluster> clusters;
}
```

This is my Cluster entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cluster")
public class Cluster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String team;

    private String concept;
}
```

This gives me the error: must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key .

How could I fix this? I don't see how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@JoinColumn` instead of `@JoinTable`

```
public class Project {
  //...
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Set<Cluster> clusters;
```

and add PROJECT_ID column to Cluster entity.

```
public class Cluster {
  //...
  @Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
  private Integer projectId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but, as far as I know about Software Engineering, what you want CAN'T be done: you can't store a relationship nowhere but in a third table. Lists, sets, maps, and so on MUST be stored that way.

Otherwise, and in your case, you'd have Project's properties replicated for each cluster of the relationship, and that's not desirable.